# How to Generate an Extended Private Key from Command Line?

Tags: private-key, linux

I'm trying to create an extended private key so I can create multiple public addresses that can be controlled using a single master key.

I have a library which handles most of what I need, but I need to provide an extended private key.

How can I generate an extended private key? Ideally I'd like to do it from linux command line.

Comment: What do you mean by ‘controlled by a single private key’? I ask because there is a common misconception that a master priv key can be used to spend coins stored at child addresses.

Comment: @chytrik making a bot that needs to create unique address for user to deposit to but was hoping to use a single private key to be able to resend those funds to a master wallet after transaction.

Comment: The master private key is used to derive the child private keys that will let you spend the funds. The master private key cannot be used to spend funds stored at child addresses. You will still need to use each individual key to sign transactions.